# Google colab unable to authenticate google drive using PyDrive

Tags: authentication, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, pydrive

I'm running a code on Google colab and I ran into an authentication problem when I mount my google drive.
I didn't have any authentication or mounting problem until now, but it stopped working all of a sudden. I don't recall any changes I made to my google account and I can access to my google drive just fine. I tested my code on Google colab with other person's account and it seems to work fine. So I'm guessing it's related to my google account. 
Anyone had a similar issue or has an idea what could've messed up this authentication?

Here's part of my code for authentication:

[image]

And this is where it's stuck and doesn't go through. (after I click the link and choose which google drive to use)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second screenshot doesn't show any particular error. Does an error appear? Does the indeterminate progress bar keep spinning? Is there an error logged in the [Javascript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools#console)

Comment: It didn't give me any error but the progress bar just kept spinning. I tried again today and it started working all of a sudden although I didn't change anything.. I'm glad that it's working now but I'm still wondering what the problem was so that I can fix it when it happens again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using `PyDrive` when authenticating Google Colab, you can use this instead:

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
ROOT = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/"
```

Now `ROOT` is the root directory of your Google drive. That's why I always follow this code with:

```
import os
os.chdir(ROOT)
```

Now, you can access your GoogleDrive the same as you do with your local disk.

Source: [official documentation](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA)

Comment: It's working again now but thank you! I'll try that as well.